My CLI script are work with NPM only. but, not for PNPM and Yarn why?
I created react boilerplate with some pre-config and push it to github. then I create a CLI tool for run script and got my starter project.
but, the problem is my script are work with npm package manager only.

npx create-ketstack-festart (work).
pnpx or pnpm dlx create-ketstack-festart (not work)
yarn create-ketstack-festart (not work)

this my code for CLI:

#!/usr/bin/env node
const { execSync } = require("node:child_process");
const path = require("node:path");
const fs = require("node:fs");
const readline = require("readline");

// Template repository URL
const templateRepo = "https://github.com/JarnKet/ketstack-festart";

// Function to prompt the user for input
const promptUser = (question) => {
    const rl = readline.createInterface({
        input: process.stdin,
        output: process.stdout,
    });

    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        rl.question(question, (answer) => {
            rl.close();
            resolve(answer.trim());
        });
    });
};

// Function to detect available package managers
const detectPackageManagers = () => {
    const managers = [];
    try {
        execSync("npm --version", { stdio: "ignore" });
        managers.push("npm");
    } catch {}
    try {
        execSync("pnpm --version", { stdio: "ignore" });
        managers.push("pnpm");
    } catch {}
    try {
        execSync("yarn --version", { stdio: "ignore" });
        managers.push("yarn");
    } catch {}
    return managers;
};

// Function to modify package.json if needed
const updatePackageJson = (appPath, appName) => {
    const packageJsonPath = path.join(appPath, "package.json");
    if (fs.existsSync(packageJsonPath)) {
        const packageJson = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(packageJsonPath, "utf8"));
        packageJson.name = appName;
        // Remove any package-manager specific configs if they exist
        delete packageJson.packageManager;
        fs.writeFileSync(packageJsonPath, JSON.stringify(packageJson, null, 2));
    }
};

(async () => {
    try {
        // Prompt the user for the project name
        const appName = await promptUser("Enter your project name: ");
        if (!appName) {
            console.error("Project name cannot be empty.");
            process.exit(1);
        }

        // Resolve the full path for the app
        const appPath = path.resolve(process.cwd(), appName);

        // Clone the template repository
        console.log("\nCloning template...");
        execSync(`git clone "${templateRepo}" "${appPath}"`, { stdio: "inherit" });

        // Remove Git history
        console.log("\nCleaning up...");
        fs.rmSync(path.join(appPath, ".git"), { recursive: true, force: true });

        // Update package.json
        updatePackageJson(appPath, appName);

        // Detect available package managers
        const availableManagers = detectPackageManagers();

        // Provide user guidance
        console.log("\nYour app is ready! ");
        console.log("\nNext steps:");
        console.log(`1. cd "${appName}"`);

        if (availableManagers.length > 0) {
            console.log("\n2. Install dependencies using one of these commands:");
            availableManagers.forEach((manager) => {
                if (manager === "npm") console.log(`   npm install`);
                if (manager === "pnpm") console.log(`   pnpm install`);
                if (manager === "yarn") console.log(`   yarn`);
            });

            console.log("\n3. Start the development server:");
            availableManagers.forEach((manager) => {
                if (manager === "npm") console.log(`   npm run dev`);
                if (manager === "pnpm") console.log(`   pnpm dev`);
                if (manager === "yarn") console.log(`   yarn dev`);
            });
        } else {
            console.log("\n2. Please install a package manager (npm, pnpm, or yarn)");
        }
        console.log();
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("\nAn error occurred during setup:", error.message);
        process.exit(1);
    }
})();

and package.json:
{
    "name": "create-ketstack-festart",
    "version": "1.0.10",
    "description": "CLI tool to create a React Vite app",
    "bin": {
        "create-ketstack-festart": "./bin/create-ketstack-festart.js"
    },
    "dependencies": {}
}


When I trying install via npx is work. but here are the problem of pnpm and yarn
pnpm:
pnpx create-ketstack-festart test-ketstack
Cloning template...
fatal: Too many arguments.

usage: git clone [<options>] [--] <repo> [<dir>]

    -v, --[no-]verbose    be more verbose
    -q, --[no-]quiet      be more quiet
    --[no-]progress       force progress reporting
    --[no-]reject-shallow don't clone shallow repository
    -n, --no-checkout     don't create a checkout
    --checkout            opposite of --no-checkout
    --[no-]bare           create a bare repository
    --[no-]mirror         create a mirror repository (implies --bare)
    -l, --[no-]local      to clone from a local repository
    --no-hardlinks        don't use local hardlinks, always copy
    --hardlinks           opposite of --no-hardlinks
    -s, --[no-]shared     setup as shared repository
    --[no-]recurse-submodules[=<pathspec>]
                          initialize submodules in the clone
    --[no-]recursive ...  alias of --recurse-submodules
    -j, --[no-]jobs <n>   number of submodules cloned in parallel
    --[no-]template <template-directory>
                          directory from which templates will be used
    --[no-]reference <repo>
                          reference repository
    --[no-]reference-if-able <repo>
                          reference repository
    --[no-]dissociate     use --reference only while cloning
    -o, --[no-]origin <name>
                          use <name> instead of 'origin' to track upstream
    -b, --[no-]branch <branch>
                          checkout <branch> instead of the remote's HEAD
    -u, --[no-]upload-pack <path>
                          path to git-upload-pack on the remote
    --[no-]depth <depth>  create a shallow clone of that depth
    --[no-]shallow-since <time>
                          create a shallow clone since a specific time
    --[no-]shallow-exclude <revision>
                          deepen history of shallow clone, excluding rev
    --[no-]single-branch  clone only one branch, HEAD or --branch
    --no-tags             don't clone any tags, and make later fetches not to follow them
    --tags                opposite of --no-tags
    --[no-]shallow-submodules
                          any cloned submodules will be shallow
    --[no-]separate-git-dir <gitdir>
                          separate git dir from working tree
    --[no-]ref-format <format>
                          specify the reference format to use
    -c, --[no-]config <key=value>
                          set config inside the new repository
    --[no-]server-option <server-specific>
                          option to transmit
    -4, --ipv4            use IPv4 addresses only
    -6, --ipv6            use IPv6 addresses only
    --[no-]filter <args>  object filtering
    --[no-]also-filter-submodules
                          apply partial clone filters to submodules
    --[no-]remote-submodules
                          any cloned submodules will use their remote-tracking branch
    --[no-]sparse         initialize sparse-checkout file to include only files at root
    --[no-]bundle-uri <uri>
                          a URI for downloading bundles before fetching from origin remote

node:child_process:965
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Command failed: git clone https://github.com/JarnKet/ketstack-festart /Users/jarnket/Documents/Personal/Code Space/ReactJS/test-ketstack
    at genericNodeError (node:internal/errors:984:15)
    at wrappedFn (node:internal/errors:538:14)
    at checkExecSyncError (node:child_process:890:11)
    at execSync (node:child_process:962:15)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/jarnket/Library/Caches/pnpm/dlx/kiis5gjbeifl2v5ol2rtn6ejcm/193257ba1fa-113d6/node_modules/.pnpm/create-ketstack-festart@1.0.1/node_modules/create-ketstack-festart/bin/create-ketstack-festart.js:19:1)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1358:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1416:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1208:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1024:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:174:12) {
  status: 129,
  signal: null,
  output: [ null, null, null ],
  pid: 3914,
  stdout: null,
  stderr: null
}

Node.js v20.15.1

yarn:
yarn create-ketstack-festart
yarn run v1.22.22
warning package.json: No license field
error Command "create-ketstack-festart" not found.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.

